# Use properties file to set directory where to load file

Tags: java

I have a java/mule application that loads a file from a directory created and displays it on the server eg localhost/file.txt

```
File dir = new File("C:\\folder");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file1 = new File(dir, filePath);
```

The filepath is taking from the URL - it takes the param `http.request.path` eg file.txt and reads the file

Is there anyway I can move the hard coded bit of code for setting the folder to a mule/java properties file instead of hard coding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the path in a properties file, and use the `Properties` class in Java, to read it.
Sample code :

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;
try {
input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
prop.load(input);
}catch(IOException e){
    //handle exception
}
```

**More details--**
You have to create a new property file, which is just a file with .properties extension. Let's call it sample.properties. You can put values, which will be key-value pairs there. This is how you will put values there :

```
dirpath = /home/dextr/Documents/docs/
fileName = puzzle.txt
```

You you will have to place the properties file in ROOT of the application or you will have to provide the relative path in order to read it.
Then you use a code like the following one to read the values in a `properties` object. Depending upon what value you need, you use the appropriate key.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SoSample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("sample.properties");
        properties.load(input);
        String dirPath = (String)properties.get("dirpath");
        System.out.println(dirPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is there a specific way to specify the path within the properties file? Currently have it at "path=C:\\folder"

Comment: This is fine. Did you try it out ?

Comment: yes i'm not sure what to change dir to in the code now - File file1 = new File(dir, filePath); as dir was hardcoded. the code for loading in the properties file seems fine but i'm sure how to use it within my code

Comment: You have two variables, one for directory path and another for file path. First, hard code them into your program, check if it runs properly and then, move those path variables to the properties file. Play with the code a little bit. Why so wary ? This is not Mainframe.

Comment: I have that all done I just can't seem to be able to load the value from the properties file. I was thinking of something like String dir = (String) p.get("path");

Comment: @gio10245 I have updated my answer, added a little more details. Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: I didn't have the properties file in the root of the project, all working now. thanks!